# How to get the field names of a list inside foreach?

Tags: c#, list, field-names

I have the following class:

```
public class ListOfVariablesToSave : List<List<int>>
{
    public List<int> controlDB { get; set; }
    public List<int> interacDB { get; set; }

    public ListOfVariablesToSave()
    {
        controlDB = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        interacDB = new List<int> { 21, 22, 23 };

        Add(controlDB);
        Add(interacDB);
    }
}
```

and the following code to write its content to a text file:

```
ListOfVariablesToSave myListOfVariablesToSave = new ListOfVariablesToSave();

StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter("fileName.txt");
foreach (List<int> DB in myListOfVariablesToSave)
{
    foreach (int varToSave in DB)
    {
        myFile.WriteLine(varToSave);
    }
}
myFile.Close();
```

What I get is:

```
1
2
3
21
22
23
```

What I would like to get is:

```
controlDB
1
2
3
interacDB
21
22
23
```

Is it possible to do this by perhaps just adding a single line of code after the first `foreach`?

Comment: Your class won't even compile, but you'd probably be better off finding a more suitable data structure that will store the name along with the data. If order isn't important you could use a `Dictionary<string,List<int>>`, if order is important, you could use `OrderedDictionary`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when writing the class the first time (I had put the `Add` outside the constructor). I just edited it and I think it should be fine now.

Comment: Descending from `List<T>` is almost always a code smell. Are you doing this just to support IEnumerable? You could probably do a lot better by just implementing `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, int>>` (or better yet, *not* implementing that interface and instead exposing a property of that type) and then using `yield return`.

Comment: No, I'm just writing variables to a text file that will be used for something else. I just want the user to know where the values came from and adding the field names would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think about doing something like this:

```
public class ListOfVariablesToSave : List<ListOfThings<int>>
{
    public ListOfThings<int> controlDB { get; set; }
    public ListOfThings<int> interacDB { get; set; }

    public ListOfVariablesToSave()
    {
        controlDB = new ListOfThings<int>() { 1, 2, 3  };
        controlDB.Name = "controlDB";
        interacDB = new ListOfThings<int>() { 21, 22, 23 };
        interacDB.Name = "interacDB";

        Add(controlDB);
        Add(interacDB);
    }

}

public class ListOfThings<T> : List<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ListOfThings() : base() { }
}
```

Instead of your `ListOfVariablesToSave` being derived from `List<List<int>>` you instead create another class that derives from `List<int>` and adds your name property.

You can then iterate like this:

```
var lists = new ListOfVariablesToSave();
foreach (var list in lists) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(list.Name);
    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get to access the name in the foreach loop? I tried `myFile.WriteLine(DB.Name);` but it doesn't work.

Comment: OK, I was using `foreach (List<string> list in lists)` instead of `foreach (var list in lists)`. Why changing to `var` solves the problem?

Comment: Giving you +1 for the non reflection method.  I used your class structure in my updated answer that has both reflection and non reflection.

Comment: @LeonardoTrivino Changing to var doesn't solve the problem.  The compiler figures out what data type to use when var is used instead of explicitly using the appropriate data type.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Comment: @LeonardoTrivino: You'd need `foreach (ListOfThings<int> list in lists)`, or you can just use `var` like I did and let the compiler figure it out.

Comment: OK. I figured it out. I was writing `List<int>` instead of `ListOfThings<int>`. My bad

Answer (score 2):

Below code is not a best way, but hope it help you more:

**Model:**

```
class ListOfVariablesToSave 
{
    public List<int> controlDB { get; set; }
    public List<int> interacDB { get; set; }
}
```

**Code:**

```
static void Main()
    {
        ListOfVariablesToSave model = new ListOfVariablesToSave();
        List<int> controlDB = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        List<int> interacDB = new List<int> { 21, 22, 23 };
        model.controlDB = controlDB;
        model.interacDB = interacDB;


        StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter("fileName.txt");
        foreach (var prop in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            myFile.WriteLine(prop.Name);
            foreach (var prop1 in model.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (String.Compare(prop1.Name, prop.Name) == 0)
                {
                    foreach (int varToSave in (List<int>)prop1.GetValue(model, null))
                    {
                        myFile.WriteLine(varToSave);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        myFile.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sticking with the first answer, which is more intuitive for me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick using reflection (Just change Console.WriteLine to go to your file instead):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ListOfVariablesToSave myListOfVariablesToSave = new ListOfVariablesToSave();

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in myListOfVariablesToSave
                 .GetType()
                 .GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | 
                                 BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                 BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly )
                 // Only get the properties of type List<int>
                 // Actual PropertyType looks like: 
                 //   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
                 .Where(p => p.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("List") && 
                        p.PropertyType.ToString().Contains("System.Int32"))
                )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pi.Name);
            (pi.GetValue(myListOfVariablesToSave) as List<int>).ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
        }
    }
}

public class ListOfVariablesToSave : List<List<int>>
{
    public List<int> controlDB { get; set; }
    public List<int> interacDB { get; set; }
    // Added this property to show that it doesn't get used in the above foreach
    public int Test {get; set;}

    public ListOfVariablesToSave()
    {
        controlDB = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
        interacDB = new List<int> { 21, 22, 23 };
        Add(controlDB);
        Add(interacDB);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
controlDB
1
2
3
interacDB
21
22
23
```

See working sample here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/4yyc8Q

### UPDATE

Less cumbersome using Matt Burland's class structures (Again, just replace Console.WriteLine to go to your file instead)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ListOfVariablesToSave myListOfVariablesToSave = new ListOfVariablesToSave();

        myListOfVariablesToSave.ForEach(m => {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Name);
            m.ForEach(m1 => Console.WriteLine(m1));
        });
    }
}

public class ListOfVariablesToSave : List<ListOfThings<int>>
{
    public ListOfThings<int> controlDB { get; set; }
    public ListOfThings<int> interacDB { get; set; }

    public ListOfVariablesToSave()
    {
        controlDB = new ListOfThings<int>() { 1, 2, 3  };
        controlDB.Name = "controlDB";
        interacDB = new ListOfThings<int>() { 21, 22, 23 };
        interacDB.Name = "interacDB";

        Add(controlDB);
        Add(interacDB);
    }

}

public class ListOfThings<T> : List<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ListOfThings() : base() { }
}
```

Results:

```
controlDB
1
2
3
interacDB
21
22
23
```

See working sample here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/CKsIFo

Comment: This does work! It's a little more cumbersome than I had hoped, but well, you can't get everything :)

Comment: Thanks. Your solution is elegant, but I'm choosing the first answer, because it's more intuitive for me. Thanks for the help.